# copy data from one tables to another one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table ***OldDocuments*** and ***Documents*** and I want to import Data from one table, ***OldDocument*** and copy it into the new table knowing that the two tables do not have the same column name numbers neither the same names.

Here are the columns I want to import to the new table

***OldDocument***

*Id(PK)

Document(BLOB)

fileName(VARCHAR)

DocumentType(VARCHAR)

user_Id(FK)*

***Document***

*Id  (PK)

Document_content (BLOB)

fileName (VARCHAR)

DocType(VARCHAR)

user_Id*(FK)

I need a query that will select from one table and copy into the new tables these columns. Something like

```
    INSERT INTO DOCUMENT(ID,document_content, fileName , DocType, user_Id) 
    VALUES (get data from the old table)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a result from another select. Here is the doc: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Ex: `INSERT INTO table2 (column_name(s)) SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1;`

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Document (Id,Document_content,fileName,DocType,user_Id)
SELECT Id,Document,fileName,DocumentType,user_Id
FROM OldDocument
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO DOCUMENT(ID,document_content, fileName , DocType, user_Id) 
SELECT ID, Document, fileName, DocumentType, user_id FROM OldDocument;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Document
SELECT Id,Document,fileName,DocumentType,user_Id
FROM OldDocument
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

```
INSERT INTO Document (ID, document_content, fileName , DocType, user_Id) 
SELECT Id, Document, filename, DocumentType, user_Id FROM OldDocument
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO DOCUMENT(ID,document_content, fileName , DocType, user_Id) 
    select Id, Document, filename, DocumentType, user_Id from OldDocument
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the general format for this type of problems correct answer

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp